# Simulating Logarithms by repeated Integer division

Tags: java, math, division, logarithm

I'm trying to write a program that simulates logarithms by repeated integer division. A user inputs a base number and a value X that they want to take the log of. The code runs through a loop and increments a count after each successive division. The code is set to stop after the value of X gets smaller than the base because I'm only using int type variables.

This code works fine for some numbers and bases but for others it gives the wrong value. It does " log_2(64) is 6 " however it doesn't do log_10 of 100. It gives a count of 10.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int base;
    int X;
    int response;
    int n=0;

  do{   
    System.out.println("Java Lab 3 Logarithm Solver.");
    System.out.println("Please enter a base > 1");
    base = inScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a number, X>0.");
    X = inScan.nextInt();
    if (X > 0 && base > 1){
        System.out.println("Logarithm base " +base+ " of " +X+" is ");
         for ( ; X>base ;n++){

            X=(X/base);
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalide numbers.");
    } 
        System.out.println("Would you like to go again? Press 1, press 0 to quit");
        response = inScan.nextInt(); 

  } while (response == 1);

 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger, such as the one provided by your IDE?

Comment: Check where `n` gets reset to zero. By the way, multiplying the base up is faster than dividing the base down.

Comment: hexafraction- Yes I did, it did not seem to help. 

Lazarus- I tried multiplying the base, it seems to work ok. I just have to fix the logic of the for loop. Thank you.

Comment: @hexafraction You got a response: "Yes I did, it did not seem to help." He didn't use the @

Comment: @AndrewLazarus You got a response: "I tried multiplying the base, it seems to work ok. I just have to fix the logic of the for loop." He didn't use the @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring n as a global variable; I suspect that if you check your tests, this algorithm works only the first time through every time you compile and run it. Instead of having n as global, declare it in your for loop like

```
for(int n = 0; X < base; n++)
```

since it looks like you need the value of n later, I suggest having a variable with a wider scope, perhaps declared in the do-while loop, to store the n in, like

```
do
{ 
    int numberOfTimesThroughLoop = 0;
    ...
    for(...)
    {
        x = x/base;
        numberOfTimesThroughLoop = n;
    }
}
```

as a side note, most of the time variables (even single letter variable, like your 'X') being with a lower case character

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. However now it prints out zero each time I run it. I suspect because i declared numberOfTimesThroughLoop = 0;